# (Android)listview divider removed, but still show blue line after click

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a listview in a LinearLayout, and i have removed its divider in xml, like this:

```
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/main_content">
        <ListView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@null"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, everytime when i click an item, a blue line will show up above the item just like a divider exists there. Then if i click somewhere else, the line goes away. How can i stop this from happening?

Comment: It seems that setting listSelector to transparent is the key. All other settings without this don't work. Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use list Selector property as below:

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

you can set it to null as well. i have set it to transparent.

Comment: I found that i only need to add this to my xml and set it to transparent. Setting to null doesn't work. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines inside your listview

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

and delete

```
android:cacheColorHint="@null"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

## use

```
<ListView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```